# Execute javascript after page loading in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, pageload

I have this HTML markup:

```
 <asp:Image ID="imgMap" runat="server" ImageUrl="/common/images/harita.jpg" class="map"
            usemap="#Map" BorderWidth="0" />

        <map name="Map" id="Map">
            <area title="City1" shape="poly" coords="266,103" href="/dealer/186/Page.aspx#dealer1" />
            <area title="City2" shape="poly" coords="255,222"  href="/dealer/186/Page.aspx#dealer2" />            
</map>
```

and

```
<div id="dealer1"></div>
<div id="dealer2"></div>
.
.
.
.
```

and Javascript code like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).ready(function () {
            var addressSection = "",
             dealer = "",
             eTop = "",
            callbackAnimate = function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(dealer).removeAttr("style").fadeIn();
                }, 1000);
            },
             animateScroll = function () {
                 $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: eTop }, 1000, function () {
                     $(dealer).effect("highlight", { color: "#fd9900" }, 500, callbackAnimate);
                 });
             };

            $('#Map').find('area').each(function (index, elArea) {
                $(this).click(function () {
                    addressSection = $(this).attr('href').split('#');
                    dealer = "#" + addressSection[addressSection.length - 1];
                    eTop = $(dealer).offset().top;
                    animateScroll();
                });
            });
        }); 
    </script>
```

What I am trying to achieve is when user click on image area and pages goes to link specified in **href** atrribute, execute javascript code after page load, so page scroll to the section **div**. With this code,scroll effect works only after page is loaded, but not for first time when user click map. Is it possible to do scrolling after page is loaded on map click?

Comment: can you add that to a fiddle, I'll try to help if you do. Hard to understand if you want to execute that on page load or if it just fails on the first time.

Comment: @bitoiu Ok. This is JSFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/siyah12/tdAeQ/13/ As I said this work when I am on the page, but no scrolling when I am comming from another page. Hope it is more clear to understand

Comment: let me take a look. So you usually navigate this page with an anchor of some sort like page#city1 and you would expect it to scroll down but this only happens when you're already in the page and you click the map correct?

Comment: @bitoiu Yes, you have understood well. I want scroll effect working also when I come from other pages. I suppose that I have to change href attribute and pass delaer1 and dealer2 as some kind of server variable. I am just thinking that puting #dealer1 in href attribute will always do unwanted effect due to the default behaviour of href attribute.

Comment: The other think you can do is pass a query argument ?city=X